# Can we multiply values to use in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I was wondering if I could have some advice on SOQL queries, I want to return a list to show in a visualforce page of all records that are similar (not related) to each other.

So I'm querying by using the current record's values..

```
 public  FilteredListingsController (ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        sc.AddFields(new List<String>{'Commercial_Or_Residential__c','Bathrooms__c','Bedrooms__c','PropertyListingType__c','Property__r.Postcode__c','Property_Address__c','Property__r.Type_of_Property__c', 'Building_Type__c','Sale_Price__c','RentAmount__c'});
        CurrentListing = (PropertyListing__c) sc.getRecord();     
        recordId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        Listings = [SELECT Name, Id, Area__c,   Settlement_Date__c, Bedrooms__c, Property__r.State__c ,Leased_Date__c, Stage__c, Property__r.Type_of_Property__c,Sale_Price__c,RentAmount__c, Property__r.Street__c, Property__r.City__c , PropertyListingType__c, 
        Property__r.Postcode__c,Bathrooms__c, Building_Type__c, Property_Address__c, Commercial_Or_Residential__c FROM PropertyListing__c WHERE  Commercial_Or_Residential__c =:CurrentListing.Commercial_Or_Residential__c AND (Bedrooms__c=:CurrentListing.Bedrooms__c OR Bathrooms__c=:CurrentListing.Bathrooms__c) AND PropertyListingType__c =:CurrentListing.PropertyListingType__c
         AND Property__r.Postcode__c=:CurrentListing.Property__r.Postcode__c AND ((Sale_Price__c <=:CurrentListing.Sale_Price__c*1.3 AND Sale_Price__c >=:CurrentListing.Sale_Price__c*0.8)  OR (RentAmount__c <=: CurrentListing.RentAmount__c*1.5 AND RentAmount__c >=: CurrentListing.RentAmount__c*0.8))AND Property__r.Type_of_Property__c Includes (:CurrentListing.Property__r.Type_of_Property__c)];
        system.debug(Listings)
        }
```

I think this is where i'm failing:

```
AND ((Sale_Price__c <=:CurrentListing.Sale_Price__c*1.3 AND Sale_Price__c >=:CurrentListing.Sale_Price__c*0.8)  OR (RentAmount__c <=: CurrentListing.RentAmount__c*1.5 AND RentAmount__c >=: CurrentListing.RentAmount__c*0.8))
```

I'm not too sure if you can directly multiply values within the query. For example I wanted all properties that are between 80% -130% of the listed sale price or 80% -150% of the listed rent amount.

any advice would be mega,
Cheers
mike.

Edit.

Thanks for the help. I removed any white spaces in the query. and created separate variables for the values and it seems to have worked a treat.
Thanks for your help.

[image: Related Properties.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is allowed in *Apex* SOQL only, and *only* for inline queries (it does not work for `Database.query` methods). Inside an inline query, you can use normal Apex, including methods like `Date.today()` or `someMapVar.values()`. Be aware of spacing, though: I would recommend that the `:` not be split from the Apex code following it, and you should not have any whitespace outside of a string in that code. If you're not getting the results you expect, you may need to use a variable instead, but your code should be working correctly as written.